# "Yale並みに学費の高い大学". Is "並みに" a suffix? "の" between "並みに" / "学費" is optional?

Tags: particle-の, suffixes

original sentence:

> 私が選んだのは、Yale並みに学費の高い大学でした。

I think that "並みに" is a **noun suffix**?

A "の" between "並みに" and "学費" is optional:

> 私が選んだのは、Yale並みに**の**学費の高い大学でした。

Why is that original sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Yale並みに means "like Yale". I would have used 並みの but 並みに makes sense as well. On the other hand にの is an impossible combination.

Comment: @永劫回帰 I agree that it makes sense. But, the grammar looks incorrect to me.

Comment: Apparently なみ is the masu-stem (連用形) of なむ, which seems to be basically obsolete as a verb in modern Japanese (but is related to 並ぶ｛なら｝).  This なむ doesn't show up in JDIC nor in my IME, but it does show up here: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/165102/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%80/

Comment: This answer (the first) might be of interest http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1072742175

Answer (score 2, accepted):

並み is a noun suffix which uses の to act adjectivally and に to act adverbially.

In this case, it basically has the image of "stand shoulder-to-shoulder with", i.e. "on the same level as".

FYI, there is another meaning 並みの～, which means completely unremarkable -- totally ordinary as well.

Comment: なみの as "unremarkable, ordinary, 普通の" is usually spelled as [並]{なみ}の, not [並]{な}みの.

Comment: @chocolate Indeed - typo on my part; thanks.

Comment: Using something adverbially in a stateless environment doesn't quite make sense (to me). Also, I've never seen a noun modified by a  に particle (only な and の). Yet, 並みに directly modifies 学費.

Comment: @khyle It modifies 高い here I believe.